# Running parallel URL downloads with a worker pool in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'd like to use Control.Concurrent.Async `mapConcurrently`  to perform parallel downloads with `http-conduit`. The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323265/running-parallel-url-downloads-in-haskell) is not sufficient for my case because I'd like to process *n* tasks but throttle the number of concurrent workers to *m*, where *m* < *n*.

It's not enough either to pass to `mapConcurrently` multiple chunks of *m*, because then the number of active workers will tend to be less than *m* since some of the tasks will complete earlier than others, leaving a utilization gap.

Is there an easy way -- nearly as easy as using `mapConcurrently` I hope -- to implement a worker-pool concurrently performing a queue of tasks until all tasks are done?

Or is it easier just to keep the Haskell simple and do process-level parallelism with `xargs -P`?

Comment: Somewhat related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191649/are-thread-pools-needed-for-pure-haskell-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution is to throttle the `IO` actions using a [semaphore](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-QSem.html#) before wrapping them in [`Concurrently`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#t:Concurrently), using a helper function like this one:

```
withConc :: QSem -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> Concurrently b)
withConc sem f = \a -> Concurrently 
    (bracket_ (waitQSem sem) (signalQSem sem) (f a))
```

We can use `withConc` in combination with [traverse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse) to perform a throttled concurrent traversal of any `Traversable` container of tasks:

```
traverseThrottled :: Int -> (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]
traverseThrottled concLevel action tasks = do
    sem <- newQSem concLevel
    runConcurrently (traverse (withConc sem action) tasks)
```

One disadvantage of this approach is that the use of `Concurrently` will create as many threads as there are tasks, and only a subset of them will be doing actual work at any given time, thanks to the semaphore.

On the other hand, threads in Haskell are cheap so I think it is an acceptable solution in cases for which the number of tasks is not very big.

**Edit:** Giving `traverseThrottled` a more general signature:

```
import Data.Traversable 
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async 
import Control.Exception

traverseThrottled :: Traversable t => Int -> (a -> IO b) -> t a -> IO (t b) 
traverseThrottled concLevel action taskContainer = do
    sem <- newQSem concLevel
    let throttledAction = bracket_ (waitQSem sem) (signalQSem sem) . action
    runConcurrently (traverse (Concurrently . throttledAction) taskContainer)
```

Comment: Thanks this answer looks great. The threads will certainly be cheaper than spinning up multiple Haskell processes with `xargs -P`

Comment: Thanks this works great. A related newbie question: somehow importing only the functions/types used in async won't work, i.e.  import Control.Concurrent.Async (Concurrently,  runConcurrently) will produce some strange error complaining that Concurrently not found. Any clue on this issue? By the way Concurrently looks like a function as it's dotted with throttledAction, but it has Capital starting letter?

Comment: @KevinZhu In Haskell, some types have value constructors with the same name as the type. Constructors start with uppercase and can be used as functions. The type `Concurrently` has the value constructor `Concurrently :: IO a -> Concurrently a`. That's what's being composed with `throttledAction`. In order to import the constructor, and not only the type, you need to write `import Control.Concurrent.Async (Concurrently (Concurrently), runConcurrently)` or the dotted shorthand `import Control.Concurrent.Async (Concurrently (..))` which imports all constructors and accessors defined in the type.

Comment: @KevinZhu If you want a pre-packaged solution, `pooledMapConcurrentlyN` from the "unliftio" package is like `traverseThrottled`, but uses a thread pool to limit the concurrency, instead of spawning all the threads in one go and then using a semaphore. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-0.2.13.1/docs/UnliftIO-Async.html#v:pooledMapConcurrentlyN

Comment: For completeness: "One disadvantage of this approach is that the use of `Concurrently` will create as many threads as there are tasks" - using [Sibit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58577568/263061), this is avoided. Our approach there (also implemented using `async`) spaws a fixed number of N worker threads, which work down the list of tasks (in the [implementation](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-10-27/unliftio-0.2.12/src/UnliftIO.Internals.Async.html#pooledMapConcurrentlyIO%27): `jobsVar :: IORef [(a, IORef b)] <- newIORef (toList jobs)`).

Answer (score 3):

The recent version of [unliftio](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-10-27/unliftio-0.2.12/UnliftIO-Async.html#g:9) has various combinators for pooled concurrency.

Adapting Niklas's code from the other anwser, you would do it using `unliftio`
like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-14.11 --install-ghc runghc --package unliftio --package say
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Say
import UnliftIO.Async

download :: Int -> IO String
download i = do
  sayString ("downloading " ++ show i)
  threadDelay 1000000 -- sleep 1 second
  sayString ("downloading " ++ show i ++ " finished")
  return "fake response"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  responses <- pooledMapConcurrentlyN 5 download [1 .. 5]
  print responses
```

In the above code, we don't spawn more than five threads. And it's output on execution:

```
$ stack pooled.hs
downloading 1
downloading 2
downloading 3
downloading 4
downloading 5
downloading 1 finished
downloading 5 finished
downloading 2 finished
downloading 3 finished
downloading 4 finished
["fake response","fake response","fake response","fake response","fake response"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use [`parallel`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-io-0.3.3/docs/Control-Concurrent-ParallelIO-Local.html#v:parallel) or `parallelInterleaved` from [parallel-io](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-io-0.3.3). It has (among others) these properties;

> 1. Never creates more or less unblocked threads than are specified to live in the pool. NB: this count includes the thread executing parallel. This should minimize contention and hence pre-emption, while also preventing starvation.
> 2. On return all actions have been performed.
> 3. The function returns in a timely manner as soon as all actions have been performed.

Comment: My usage isn't really for parallelism of N workers across N cores, but concurrency where HTTP requests can take random amounts of time to complete and leave the processor idle while waiting for the network. Is `parallel-io` appropriate for the latter case too?

Comment: @dan Yes, a `Pool` defines the _m_ amount of workers to be used, and then they process a given list of _n_ tasks so that every time _m_ workers are executing.

Comment: If I use parallel-io do I always have to compile with the extra flags `-threaded and supply +RTS -N2 -RTS` to make it work? That seems a little annoying.

Comment: @dan If giving `-RTS` at runtime is inconvenient, you can set it at compile time with GHC's `-with-rtsopts` option.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** My answer is now obsolete, use [Sibi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155068/running-parallel-url-downloads-with-a-worker-pool-in-haskell/58577568#58577568), as we put an implementation of this solution into `unliftio`.

You can use `monad-par` for it, which, like `async`, is made by Simon Marlow.

Example:

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Par.Combinator (parMapM)
import Control.Monad.Par.IO (runParIO)

download :: Int -> IO String
download i = do
  putStrLn ("downloading " ++ show i)
  threadDelay 1000000 -- sleep 1 second
  putStrLn ("downloading " ++ show i  ++ " finished")
  return "fake response"


main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- "pooled" mapM
  responses <- runParIO $ parMapM (\i -> liftIO $ download i) [1..10]
  mapM_ putStrLn responses
```

Compile with `ghc --make -threaded PooledMapM.hs`, run like `./PooledMapM +RTS -N2`.

You'll see the output:

```
downloading 10
downloading 9
downloading 9 finished
downloading 10 finished
downloading 8
downloading 7
downloading 8 finished
downloading 7 finished
downloading 6
downloading 5
downloading 6 finished
downloading 5 finished
downloading 4
downloading 3
downloading 4 finished
downloading 3 finished
downloading 2
downloading 1
downloading 2 finished
downloading 1 finished
fake response
fake response
fake response
fake response
fake response
fake response
fake response
fake response
fake response
fake response
```

Code also available via https://gist.github.com/nh2/bfa3f182da9d13baa536

Comment: Can you control the parallelism amount by something else than RTS parameter?

Comment: @phadej For that case, Petr's answer with `parallel-io` seems like a good fit.