# A list of actions effected concurrently in parts

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, concurrency

I have a list of strings that represent shell commands, and I would like to execute, say, 10 at a time concurrently.  This is my first real foray into concurrent programming in Haskell, and I'm having some trouble.

My thought was to chunk the list into sublists of ten elements, and then `mapM_` a function that spawns each of the ten commands at the same time, waiting for each to finish before moving on to the next group of ten.  Yet every different library/approach I use/take seems to just launch every command in the list at the same time.

Suppose I have the most simple function to execute a shell command:

```
import System.Process    

execShellCommand :: String -> IO ()
execShellCommand cmd = void $ createProcess (shell cmd)
```

The naive approach

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List.Split.Internals

runChunks :: [String] -> IO ()
runChunks as = mapM_ (mapM_ execShellCommand) $ chunksOf 10 as
```

executes all the commands in the list at once (I've tried using the `waitFor` functions from Conduit.Process, with similar outcome).  Let's try to be a bit more thoughtful, and redefine the function `execShellCommand` to use `Control.Concurrent`:

```
import Control.Concurrent

execShellCommand :: String -> IO ()
execShellCommand cmd = do
  m <- newEmptyMVar
  r <- void $ createProcess (shell cmd)
  forkIO $ putMVar m r
  takeMVar m

runChunks :: [String] -> IO ()
runChunks [] = return ()
runChunks as = do
  mapM_ execShellCommand $ take 10 as
  runChunks $ drop 10 as
```

also does the same thing (runs all commands in the list at once).  Yet another library with the same outcome:

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async

runChunks :: [String] -> IO ()
runChunks [] = return ()
runChunks as = do
  ck <- mapM (async . execShellCommand) $ take 10 as
  mapM_ wait ck
  runChunks $ drop 10 as
```

I'm either not grasping a concept here, in which case I would very much appreciate a clarifying explanation, or I've just not seen a library function that can achieve the effect I'm aiming for; for the latter, an example would be extremely helpful.  Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Unrelated: you should not import `Internal` modules. In this case, you can import `Data.List.Split` instead.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29155440/1364288 for another approach that doesn't involve chunking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit curious as to what you tried with `waitFor`. Here's my first attempt:

```
import System.Process

commands = ["./demo.sh " ++ show n | n <- [1..10]]

chunksOf _ [] = []
chunksOf n xs = take n xs : chunksOf n (drop n xs)

spawn cmd = do
  (_,_,_,proc) <- createProcess (shell cmd)
  return proc

spawnAndAwaitGroup cmds = do
  procs <- mapM spawn cmds
  mapM_ waitForProcess procs

main = do
  mapM_ spawnAndAwaitGroup (chunksOf 3 commands)
```

Note how the IO actions are composed; the waits need to fit between spawns, so we apply both operations at a chunk level. We could have created the `spawn` actions en masse, but `waitForProcess` requires the returned handles. Thus I used `mapM` and the `do` `<-`.

Test run using this in `demo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1 starting
sleep 3
echo $1 ending
```

Output:

```
2 starting
1 starting
3 starting
3 ending
1 ending
2 ending
4 starting
5 starting
6 starting
4 ending
5 ending
6 ending
7 starting
8 starting
9 starting
7 ending
8 ending
9 ending
10 starting
10 ending
```

Of note, this is a purely sequential program, not concurrent at the Haskell level. It's equivalent to this shell script:

```
./demo.sh 1 &
./demo.sh 2 &
./demo.sh 3 &
wait
./demo.sh 4 &
./demo.sh 5 &
./demo.sh 6 &
wait
./demo.sh 7 &
./demo.sh 8 &
./demo.sh 9 &
wait
./demo.sh 10 &
wait
```

All the concurrent behaviour happens at OS level, in the interaction of the spawned processes.