# Concurrent HTTP requests in Haskell

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, concurrency

I have a set of functions designed to construct a tree of subtasks from the Asana API. To do this I have a fairly simple module called "Asana.hs", whose most important two functions are these ones using `Network.HTTP.Simple` to perform the requests:

```hs
getTasksForProject :: String -> String -> IO [Task]
getTasksForProject token projectId = getFromAsana token $ "projects/" ++ projectId ++ "/tasks"

getSubtasks :: String -> String -> IO [Task]
getSubtasks token taskId = getFromAsana token $ "tasks/" ++ taskId ++ "/subtasks"
```

The problem is when I want to construct a graph of all the tasks I have to:

1. get a list of tasks
2. iterate through those tasks getting their subtasks
3. recurse

For example, I have these functions to construct a "graph" of nodes and edges:

```hs
type TaskGraph = ([Task], [Edge])

merge :: TaskGraph -> TaskGraph -> TaskGraph
merge (aTasks, aEdges) (bTasks, bEdges) = (aTasks ++ bTasks, aEdges ++ bEdges)

makeEdge :: Relation -> Task -> Task -> Edge
makeEdge rel parent child = Edge rel (taskId parent) (taskId child)

rFetchTaskGraph :: String -> Task -> IO TaskGraph
rFetchTaskGraph token task = do
  subtasks <- getSubtasks token $ taskId task
  let edges = map (makeEdge Subtask task) subtasks
  foldr merge ([task], edges) <$> mapM (rFetchTaskGraph token) subtasks
```

This is extremely slow as it makes each HTTP request in sequence as far as I can tell. If I were doing this in something like Javascript, Promises would allow me to eagerly execute all the computations, but queue the requests, therefore only resolving the relevant Promise when the request is complete, but centralising the parallelism into some sort of connection pool manager.

How can I improve the efficiency of this in Haskell? I had a few thoughts:

1. Perhaps I need to create a new Monad to represent this pooled resource access?
2. Can I eagerly compute the whole list (insofar as I can, of course, since some of the requests will only be known once the results of others return)?
3. Do I need to explicitly use threads?

Comment: Sounds like a good use-case for [`haxl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxl), but I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
mapM (rFetchTaskGraph token) subtasks
```

use

```
mapConcurrently (rFetchTaskGraph token) subtasks
```

where [`mapConcurrently`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.3/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:mapConcurrently) is from the [async](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) library.

However, when making concurrent HTTP requests, one should be careful to throttle them so as not to overwhelm the remote server—or get banned by it. One simple way of doing throttling involves gating all the invocations of `rFetchTaskGraph` using a [semaphore](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-QSem.html), as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29155440/1364288).

Because `rFetchTaskGraph` is recursive, it should accept the semaphore as argument in order to pass it to its sub-calls:

```
rFetchTaskGraph :: QSem -> String -> Task -> IO TaskGraph
rFetchTaskGraph sem token task = 
    bracket_ 
      (waitQSem sem) 
      (signalQSem sem)
      (do
        subtasks <- getSubtasks token $ taskId task
        let edges = map (makeEdge Subtask task) subtasks
        foldr merge ([task], edges) <$> mapConcurrently (rFetchTaskGraph sem token) subtasks)
```

More comprehensive solutions would involve thread pools and/or [concurrent](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm) [queues](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-chans).

**Edit:** I think the previous code might lead to deadlocks in practice because the scope of the critical section is too big. Something like this should work better:

```
rFetchTaskGraph sem token task = do
       subtasks <- bracket_ (waitQSem sem) (signalQSem sem) $ getSubtasks token $ taskId task
       let edges = map (makeEdge Subtask task) subtasks
       foldr merge ([task], edges) <$> mapConcurrently (rFetchTaskGraph sem token) subtasks
```

That is, limit the critical section only to the actual HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I'll look into all those options as throttling was an important follow-up question for me.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you signal that the unit of `QSem` is available immediately after waiting for it? Wouldn't this release a resource while it's still "in use", i.e. if that `do` block takes a very long time, then you would have the same problem of lots of operations running simultaneously?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't understand what `bracket` did but looked it up on hoogle: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket

Comment: @GTF I think my throttling code might have a problem. It wraps *both* the `getSubtasks` call and the recursive step.  But this might lead to deadlocks. Perhaps you shold limit the scope of that `bracket_` only to the `getSubtasks token $ taskId task` part.

Comment: Ah hah! That's why my code hangs infinitely ><. I'll experiment and see if your suggestion fixes it.

Comment: What's sort of weird about this is that with concurrency of 30 I get about 8" loading time, but with concurrency of 1 I get 12" loading time on the Asana API. I would have expected higher benefits of concurrency but I'm not that sure how to instrument this.

Comment: Although if I revert the code to having no use of Control.Concurrent.Async then it takes 1'22" to load the same data so just adding `mapConcurrently`, even with concurrency 1, makes an enormous difference. Does that make sense?

Comment: @GTF I find surprising that there's improvement even with concurrency `1`.  My intuition says that it should take as much time as the sequential version. You could try putting `putStrLn` statements at the beginning and end of each request to get a sense of how they execute (maybe also print the durations, to see if they stay consistent). You might also create "fake" tasks with `Control.Concurrent.threadDealy` and see if they behave differently. Perhaps the concatenations in `merge` are being inefficient? What happens if you use `Data.Sequence` instead, or if you always return empty lists?

Comment: what I did instead to work this out was to profile the code and I can see that most of the time (I think) is spent in `getFromAsana` which is where the HTTP requests and deserialisation (via Aeson) happen. The cumulative time in `merge` is almost none.